# Recognizing Set cards in an image

Tags: android, image-processing, neural-network

I am writing an android app that finds solutions to a given Set game.  I would like to process the image and convert it into an array of Cards, which is a class I have already written.  However, I have not done any image processing before, but my plan was to create a neural network using something like Neuroph to identify each card, but there are 81 different cards, so that seems time consuming.  My other idea was to recognize the card independent of color to reduce the number of possible cards to 27, but I still don't know how to do this. For example, if I used this image:
[image]

I want to be able to extract that the first one is a single purple oval without a fill, the second is 3 green diamonds that are filled and the third is 2 red squiggles that are striped.

Comment: It is unclear just what your asking, are you asking what the best way is to detect the different cards? If so you need to edit your question to includes a clear question :)

Answer (score 0):

## Objective 1 : identify unique cards

This is fairly straight forward by using the feature vector of training image recognition neural nets like InceptionV3.  There are [instructions online](https://code.oursky.com/tensorflow-svm-image-classifications-engine/) for using InceptionV3 to recognize your specific thing.  Heck, you only need to get the bottleneck feature for each unique card as part of your training set.  When you get a new card get its bottleneck feature and compare it (using [cosine distance](https://www.google.ca/search?q=cosine%20distance&oq=cosine%20dist&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2095j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) to the unique cards bottleneck features.  The one with the smallest cosine distance is the likely match.  This is only 1 training example per unique card.

## Objective 2 : give cards names

Store the name with the example and bottleneck feature vector of each card.

## Addition

If you have time to give more than 1 example per type of card, do so.  Your data structure will how be [ card type , bottleneck feature vector ] and another of [ card type , card name ].  This won't scale well for thousands of training examples, but it will to fabulously well with just a handful of examples per card type.